# Refresh the form after lines are received

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm passing lines from SO to a destination form. I have created a method where I'm assigning values from SO lines in for loop in destination form dataSource which I call from initValue. Here is the code sample:

```
for (counter = 1; counter <= conLen(c); counter++)
    {
        salesLineLocal = conPeek(c, counter);
        ttsBegin;
        .........
        table.doInsert();
        ttsCommit;
    }
```

When initialization is done and form opens I see only 1 line despite of let say 3. but when I press F5 all lines are shown correctly.
So, what I'm doing then is to refresh table_ds by code after for loop.
I tried table_ds.research(); but did not help. Then I tried element.task(#taskF5); but neither it hepled.
What is the correct method to override on form and put code there, so that the lines appear with form opening?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you call your method from `initValue` and not from e.g. `init`?

Comment: I tried to call from init of form but initValue of datasource is called after it and values are overwritten somewhere.

Comment: `initValue` on the datasource is called when the record is being created, it is a place to populate the record with initial values for the fields.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I have understood the question.

I suggest you be careful where you put the code , with **true** `boolean`.
The method research it must be called correctly, after `ttsCommit;`.

```
table_ds.research(true);
```

Another thing, if you press F5 all lines are shown correctly, you can use this code:

```
element.task(2839);
element.task(2876);
```

Using numbers 2839-2876 I found ambiguity.

Attention by this method just reread the value.
The good way It would be to write a bit of code in the `active` method in tour dataSource, but if everything works properly, you should fix it, I hope.

I prefer the `research` method.

My references and help page are these:

http://kashperuk.blogspot.it/2010/03/tutorial-reread-refresh-research.html

[How to refresh form when I open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913729/how-to-refresh-form-when-i-open)

https://calebmsdax.wordpress.com/2013/11/28/no-more-press-f5-in-dynamics-ax/

http://axrachit.blogspot.it/2013/11/ax2012restore-or-ctrl-f5-command-on.html

I hope to be a help, or giving you some advice.
Thanks for your attention

enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

If you have your datasource table linked (or query fetch mode set to `1:n`), then you have to research root datasource.

Comment: I did it also but same issue.
The root datasource is CustInvoiceTable and CustInvoiceLine has LinkType "Active" to it