# How to refresh form when I open?

Tags: forms, refresh, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a CheckBox in my TabPage on my Form, if I select the checkBox, the value is saved in a Table field (present in my FormDataSource: ParametersTable).

I want to refresh the form when I enter in TabPage, just Like pressing F5.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a great article about different methods of refreshing the form's data [here](http://kashperuk.blogspot.com/2010/03/tutorial-reread-refresh-research.html). Here are the basic outline:

## **1. Refresh**

This method basically refreshes the data displayed in the form controls with whatever is stored in the form cache for that particular datasource record. Calling refresh() method will **NOT** reread the record from the database. So if changes happened to the record in another process, these will not be shown after executing `refresh()`.

## 2.  Reread

Calling `reread()` will query the database and re-read the current record contents into the datasource form cache. This will not display the changes on the form until a redraw of the grid contents happens (for example, when you navigate away from the row or re-open the form).
You should not use it to refresh the form data if you have through code added or removed records.

## 3. Research

Calling `research()` will rerun the existing form query against the database, therefore updating the list with new/removed records as well as updating all existing rows. This will honor any existing filters and sorting on the form, that were set by the user.

## 4. ExecuteQuery

Calling `executeQuery()` will also rerun the query and update/add/delete the rows in the grid. `ExecuteQuery` should be used if you have modified the query in your code and need to refresh the form to display the data based on the updated query.

I strongly recommand that you read the article. Try to use some of the methods above or some combinations of them.

Start with `research()` method, it might solve your problem:

```
formDataSource.research();
```